# Вывод таблицы в телеграм бот aiogram sqlite3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

[image: необходимая таблица]

Есть таблица, из которой нужно вывести столбцы 'username' и 'kol после сообщения от пользователя <Топ> в формате:

1. name - kol
2. name2 - kol
3. name3 - kol

и выполнить сортировку по столбцу 'kol' (сверху самый высокий результат, снизу самый низкий).

Главная проблема в том, что у некоторых людей нет тг-username и надо это как-то решить.

Вывести нужно, допустим, первые 10 строк.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой набросок на Google Таблицах, с использованием numpy, который вам может понадобиться, когда наберётся большое количество пользователей

```
import numpy as np
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import gspread

API_TOKEN = '<bot_token>'
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
gs = gspread.service_account(filename='<service_account_info>')
sh = gs.open_by_key('<gdocs_access_key>')


@dp.message_handler(commands='top')
async def top10(message: types.Message):
    text = ''
    # Берём страницу с результатами из Google Таблиц
    topspr = sh.get_worksheet('<int>')
    # Берём значения из 3-ёх столбцов: userID, username, kol
    top = np.array(topspr.get_all_values()[1:])[:, 1:4]  
    # Сортируем массив по очкам, потом username по алфавиту
    top = np.flip(top[np.lexsort((top[:, 1], np.int64(top[:,2])))], axis=0)  
    # Проходим по первой 10-ке лидеров
    for x in top[:10]:
        if x[1] != '':  # Если username есть выводим
            text += f'{x[1]} - {x[2]}\n'
        else:  # Если его нет, используем ID
            text += f'ID{x[0]} - {x[2]}\n'
    await message.answer(text=text)


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Если можно как-то пройтись по массиву без for'а, прошу не ругать, я не особо хорошо знаком с numpy

Comment: Большое спасибо, но я бы хотел понять как это делать именно с sql. Все равно для общего развития ваш код очень подойдет

Answer (score 0):

можно же упомянуть пользователя с помощью его id вместо юзернейма

```
top = ... # список топ 10 человек в таком формате: ((user_id, user_firstname, kol), ...)
# Думаю вы сами можете вывести из бд 10 человек

text = ''
numeration = 0
for i in top:
    user_id = i[0]
    user_name = i[1] # Имя человека, а не юзернейм
    kol = i[2]

    numeration += 1

    text += f'\n{numeration}. <a href="tg://user?id={user_id}">{user_name}</a> - {kol}'

await send_message(msg.from_user.id, text, 'html')
#                                            /\
# Нада указать parse_mode как html так как я использовал форматирования html чтобы упомянуть
```